# TypeError: $(...).visualize is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I include a javascript file that displays a chart and I get this message : **TypeError: $(...).visualize is not a function**

I tried with **jQuery().visualize** and this is the same thing.

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' }).appendTo('body');
    });
</script>
```

Libraries :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.visualize.plugin.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

I'm new in javascript, I don't understand.

Comment: Show me where you include your js libraries

Comment: Look in your console - It might toss an include-error. And look if the libraries are included right

Comment: try loading jquery first.

Comment: the script tags are in the wrong order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you include visualize library before you include jQuery. Swap the includes in places as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.visualize.plugin.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your including - JQuery must be added first.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.visualize.plugin.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `jquery.visualize.plugin.js` AFTER jQuery. It's dependent.

You can also remove the `language="javascript"`.
Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.visualize.plugin.js"></script>
```

Comment: well you even dont even need the type tag cause script is by default javascript ;)